# Testing JavaFx App For Different Screen Resolution

Tags: testing, javafx, screen-resolution

This might seem a bit off-topic but I have a JavaFX app that I need to test(scaling) for different screen resolution. My problem is I have a Windows 8.1 PC running at maximum resolution  of 1366x768 but I need to test it for 1920x1080, 1440x900,1600x900 etc. Any idea on how to achieve this will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to buy a new graphics and/or monitor.

But if you want to avoid that, you can try testing your app in a virtual machine. I know in VirtualBox, if you set the virtual machine'e resolution higher than the native resolution you will just get scroll bars with the set resolution. So all the scaling should be the same as if you were running it on a higher native resolution.